# read multiple root tree file one by one

Tags: c++, string, ifstream

I am a beginner, This is related to assignment work.

For one root tree file (here pp1.root), I can use the below code. If I am having 10 root files and I need to read each file one by one to get the statistical parameters.

```
void pbtrue()

{
   
TFile *f = new TFile("pp1.root");
TTree *T1 = (TTree*)f->Get("T1");

int Tcharged ;
int Neg_charged ;
int Posi_charged ;
int delta_charge;
T1->SetBranchAddress("Totalcharge",&Tcharged);
T1->SetBranchAddress("negativecharge",&Neg_charged);
T1->SetBranchAddress("positivecharge",&Posi_charged);
T1->SetBranchAddress("deltacharge",&delta_charge);
int nentries = T1->GetEntries();
cout<< "Entries : "<<nentries<<endl;
double sumT=0.0;
double sumN=0.0;
double sumP=0.0;
double sumD=0.0;
double meanT=0.0;
double meanN=0.0;
double meanP=0.0;
double meanD=0.0;
for (int i=0;i<nentries;i++) {
T1->GetEntry(i);
sumT += Tcharged; 
sumN += Neg_charged; 
sumP += Posi_charged; 
sumD += delta_charge; 
 
meanT=sumT/nentries;
meanN=sumN/nentries;
meanP=sumP/nentries;
meanD=sumD/nentries;
}
cout << "mean of Total charge  : "<<meanT<<endl;
cout << "mean of Negative charge  : "<<meanN<<endl;
cout << "mean of positive charge : "<<meanP<<endl;
cout << "mean of delta charge : "<<meanD<<endl;
```

The way I have to do the calculation is by reading each root file one by one. Every root file contains the same branches and same variables. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Please help you to do WHAT?  If you pass the file name as a parameter to that function, you could call the function repeatedly with different file names.

Comment: I am new to c++ , I don't know how to pass it

Comment: I'm surprised by your comment.  You wouldn't have been given an assignment of this complexity unless you had covered functions and parameter passing.  `void pbtrue( const char * filename )`, then `TFile *f = new TFile(filename);`.  Now you can call the function with `pbtrue("pp1.root");` or `pbtrue("other.root");`.  Later you will learn how to pass that as a `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can do this using [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [std::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to form `filename` and use its `c_str` method to get pointer to underlying character array (*C-style string*) to pass it to `TFile` constructor if it doesn't accept `std::string`:

```
// ...
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
{
    string filename = "pp"+to_string(i)+".root";
    TFile *f = new TFile(filename.c_str());
    // ...
}
// ...
```

so it will read pp1.root, pp2.root, ..., pp100.root and process them in order.